# How to choose both Time and Date in JSpinner?

Tags: java, timer, jspinner

Using the code below I tried to change and choose a Time and Date from the JSpinner.

Actually I can just change the Time as it's formatted.

Should I try to add a separated JSpinner with SpinnerDatamodel ?

Is there a possiblity to change the Date too ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SpinnerTest {

 Timer timer;
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   new SpinnerTest().startApp();
 }

 private void startApp() {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSpinner Sample");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerDateModel();
 JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);
 spinner1.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1, "HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy"));
 spinner1.addChangeListener(new CalendarListener());

 JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Dates/Date");
 JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
 panel1.add(spinner1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 frame.setSize(200, 90);
 frame.setVisible(true);
}


 private class CalendarListener implements ChangeListener {
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)  {
   JSpinner jSpinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
   Date date = (Date) jSpinner.getValue();
   long delay = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
   timerStart();
   if (delay > 0) {
   timer.setInitialDelay((int) delay);
   timer.restart();
  }
 }   
}

private void timerStart() {
 this.timer = new Timer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (ActionEvent evt) -> {
 System.out.println("okey");
});}
```

}

Comment: Normally a UI would use two spinners, one for date and one for time.

Comment: Yes it works, but how could I implement it to choose all separate like "HH" then "mm" then "ss" and so on, should it work ? I tried it but the trigger of timer doesn't work. Before I could change only Hour and Day and it triggered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could let it work.

It needed the same Date value with just one JSpinner.

And to choose the values, it needs to be pressed in the middle of the numbers(Hour,Minute etc.).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SpinnerTest {

 Timer timer;
 Date date;
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   new SpinnerTest().startApp();
 }

 private void startApp() {
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSpinner Sample");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 date = new Date();
 SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerDateModel(date,null,null,0);
 JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);

 spinner1.addChangeListener(new CalendarListener());
 spinner1.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner1, "HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"));

 JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Times/Dates");
 JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

 panel2.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
 panel1.add(spinner1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);


 frame.setSize(200, 90);
 frame.setVisible(true);
}


 private class CalendarListener implements ChangeListener {
  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)  {

 JSpinner jSpinner = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
 date = (Date) jSpinner.getValue() ;


 long delay = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
 //System.out.println(delay);
  timerStart();
  if (delay > 0) {
  timer.setInitialDelay((int) delay);
  timer.restart();
 }
}
```

}

```
 private void timerStart() {
  this.timer = new Timer(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (ActionEvent evt) -> {
  System.out.println("okey");
 });}
}
```